# Optimizing repeated query (mask) of large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a pandas dataframe which has around 350 columns and 500000 rows initially:

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

cols = list(string.ascii_lowercase) + [i+j for i,j in [*itertools.combinations(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 2)]]
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat([np.random.randint(2)], [500000]) for col in cols})
```

I need to add 3000 new columns to my dataframe (initialized to 0) where the value of each row depends on the values in the existing rows (I use a mask when testing for this):

```
for i, j, k in itertools.combinations(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 3):
    df[i+j+k] = 0
    df.loc[(df[i] > 0) & (df[j] > 0) & (df[k] > 0) & (df[i + j] + df[i + k] + df[j + k] >= 2), i+j+k] = 1
```

However, the issue is that the above loop is extremely slow! Is there a way to optimize the procedure above? Perhaps using a pandas lookup-function that is faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a much faster solution. When you get stuck in performance problems of this type, try switching to Numpy. It is way faster!

Assure it fits in your memory before you run it :D

```py
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

cols = list(string.ascii_lowercase) + [i+j for i,j in [*itertools.combinations(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 2)]]
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat([np.random.randint(2)], [500000]) for col in cols})
mat = df.values  # Convert to numpy, much faster


additional_cols = []
for i, j, k in itertools.combinations(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 3):
    cond_1 = (mat[:,cols.index(i)]*mat[:,cols.index(j)]*mat[:,cols.index(k)])>0  # Singles
    cond_2 = (mat[:,cols.index(i+j)]+mat[:,cols.index(i+k)] + mat[:,cols.index(j+k)])>2  # Multiples
    col = (cond_1 & cond_2) + 0  # +0 transforms to int
    additional_cols.append((i+j+k, col))

df_additional = pd.DataFrame(dict(additional_cols)) # Assure it fits in memory
df = pd.concat([df, df_additional], axis=1)  # Assure it fits in memory
```